# Regular expression for validating word counts less than 100

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regular expression that can validate a textarea so that user is not able to type more than 100 words across the multiple lines. I have tried something like this

`^(?:\b\w+\b[\s\r\n]*){0,100}$`

but as soon as I type some special character like dot (.) or comma (,) the expression failed.
[image]

Comment: Does it have to be regex? It would be simpler to do string manipulation - split on spaces and count the chunks. It could be slightly inaccurate but should be good enough for most use cases.

Comment: I need to put in some CMS, it just accepts regex.

Comment: you can use `\W` instead of your `[\s\r\n]`, this will cover non-space non-word characters as well.

Comment: You may use `^\s*(?:\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,99}\s*)?$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\s*(?:\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,99}\s*)?$
```

If at least one word must be present remove the outer `(?:` / `)?` optional non-capturing grouping construct:

```
^\s*\S+(?:\s+\S+){0,99}\s*$
```

Details:

- `^` - start of string
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `\S+` - 1 or more non-whitespaces
- `(?:\s+\S+){0,99}` - 0 to 99 repetitions of 1 or more whitespaces followed with 1 or more nonwhitespaces
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

To count only words consisting of word chars replace each `\s` with `\W` and each `\S` with `\w`.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: As mentioned in the comments, this regex has limitations. Please use the solution offered in the accepted answer.]

Try this:`^(?:[\b\w\b;:,\.]+[\s\r\n]*){0,100}$`

If needed, add other possible punctuations and non-alphanumeric characters where you see `;:,\.`.

Edit: Left 4 in the regex as I was testing with a smaller number of words. Replaced with 100 as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Not the downvoter but do you know that `\b` inside a character class means `backspace`, dot doesn't need to be escaped in character class and `\s` already includes `\r` and `\n`? What about characters like `$!'"#@(){}...`

Comment: Thanks. I like explanations like these and now won't even mind if you downvote.